# Can I play two Origin games on the same account at the same time?

Tags: origin

I have Battlefield 3 and The Sims 3 on my Origin account. My girlfriend wants to play The Sims on her PC at the same time I'm playing BF3 online on my PC. Is this possible?

Comment: You can only be logged into an Origin account from one computer at a time. Logging in from another computer will log you out of the other session. I am not sure if you need Origin connectivity to play Sims 3 if it is already started. Therefore, your gf would log in to Origin, start up The Sims 3 and play that. Then you log into your PC and play BF3. If Sims 3 doesn't worry about Origin after it is started, this should work. Unfortunately, I can't confirm this at the moment.

Comment: And sorry for another comment so shortly after my first, but you might consider getting another Humble Bundle. It is worth it and it does go to a good cause. You'll have to be quick though, it is only running for another ~3 hours or so. Greater than $4.93 unlocks the Sims 3 and BF3.

Comment: I have actually had this work myself doing something similar. But that was before Origin started cracking down (Two years ago). Girlfriend wanted to play sims and I wanted to play Need for Speed. You should be good with Nick's method for now though. Sims only looks for connections to Facebook and Twitter after it has been verified with Origin. Again, buy [a new humble bundle for $5](http://www.humblebundle.com)

Answer (score 4):

It *might be* possible, but I'd recommend you just spend the extra to buy another license.

Your Origin account (including the games on it) is for your personal use only. Anything more is a violation of their EULA. So **no**, it is not possible *without* violating the license agreement.

Comment: +1 about license agreement, BUT you have 5 activations per game with Origin. Technically you're not violating it because you own the game and are playing one copy of one game on a separate computer than one copy of another game.

Comment: @ColeBusbyakacheat117cole108 That's something I didn't know about sims, let me check and edit if necessary.

Comment: Edited my comment, Check Origin.

Comment: @ColeBusbyakacheat117cole108 Maybe on Origin, but for the Humble Bundle Sims 3, you only get a key for thesims3.com, which can [only be activated once](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10221029/disagreed.PNG)

Comment: The [Community Key is for the expansions for Sims 3](http://support.humblebundle.com/customer/portal/articles/1259953-sims-3---humble-origin-bundle). This unlocks the special items in the store and allows you to access the DLC. This is separate from the origin activation, Sims can be activated/installed on 5 machines. Before uninstallation you need to de-authorize the machine freeing up the license for another machine. Sometimes the activations get used up by dying hard drives and non-deauth'ed machines. To fix that issue you must put in a support ticket. I've been there, Done that.

Comment: @ColeBusbyakacheat117cole108 I do *not* have a Origin key in my bundle. I only have a key that activates the game on the website.

Comment: Oh that's right! I get confused, I bought it twice, well now three times with the humble bundle. Once from sims3.com and once from origin. Regardless the information still stands, 5 activations of the game from the client and each activation must still be de-activated upon uninstall. They don't have it posted I believe, but I can say for sure, 5 licenses per each copy of sims that you own. (I can officially say I have fifteen licenses now. :D)

Comment: @Cloe Those five licenses are for your own personal use.  They're not for handing out, or using technicalities to support someone else using your account.  That's against Origin's terms, I would expect.

Comment: Regarding The Sims 3 keys. It was originally an Origin key. Not sure when it got changed. Either way, it has now disappeared from the page. I best check my other halves Origin account now, to check   it hasn't been removed, as she definitely activated it.

Comment: @fbueckert Im not saying that, technically sharing an account with a family member/better half is common and therefore falls in the scope. Technicalities be damned, If you paid for a license then you've paid for the game. If you happen to play two games on the same account then you're still within the boundaries of the terms of use, as you are not violating one acconut per game nor are you violating copyrights. loophoole = loophole. besides that the origin account != Sims 3 account.

Comment: Sims can be activated and download from the website, it is not subject to origin, it is technically two different accounts, but in the same network. Think of it as sims.stackexchange.com and stackoverflow.com, two accounts linked by openid. Sims uses Origin ID, as Open ID. Origin should not be required for download.

Comment: @Cole You're still using a technicality to justify your means.  You're free to do that personally all you like, but please don't bring it here.  That's getting a little too close to piracy and evading terms of service for my liking.

Comment: @fbueckert I dont see how this is anywhere close to piracy. You are sharing one account within the same household. No more piracy than allowing your brother/sister/cousin play the game while youre not playing it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. I know your post was two years ago, but this might help others. Your girlfriend will need to log in, load up the game, and then you log in on your computer. It will log her off, but wont kick her off of the game. You then can play online. I know this from experience. I share an account with 2-3 other people, and we all play Sims 4 at the same time. That is how we do it, and if we ever need online, we quit the game, log out, and log back in, making the new person who has loged on the one that is in online mode.

I hope this helps!

Comment: What you are doing (gameshare) is against TOS of Origin